# how to run/start redmine in fastcgi in dreamhost

Tags: redmine, dreamhost, fastcgi

Im using dreamhost (fastcgi as recommended in wiki-dreamhost-redmine) and install redmine over it. With webrick its working perfectly, however i see it's not recomended to keep production in webrick, nevertheless i cannot keep it either because nohub is not working (command is not found error, weird!)

I checked the available discussions about redmine production pass about httpd.conf, however its not allowed to update httpd.conf file in dreamhost. There are some other options for passenger, however in the wiki page of dreamhost, it's recomended to use fastcgi for redmine. Another option that i could have found for fastcgi is updating dispatch.fcgi file, however it's not clear how to update it nor how to start it after this update.

Anyone has ever tried redmine in dreamhost with fastcgi in production, so they can recommend something??

Answer (score 0):

This is the wiki you're referring to, correct? http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Redmine

I was able to dig this up and it seems it may be directly related to your situation, though it's tough to be sure without seeing. Hopefully it is relevant and can provide some additional info: http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/69

Ellice S

DreamHost Staff